# The font its not changing with different screen resolution/size (jquery tabletogrid)

Tags: jquery, resize, resolution

I'm having a little bit of a trouble with jquery plugin tabletogrid.(http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php)

The thing is i have my grid, with data on it, but if the user is using a different screen resolution, a worst one, the numbers are not able to be read, they don't fit on the cell, even if they use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>scroll</kbd> to resize it the numbers font grows or decrease in size but still wont be able to be read.

For ex. the time is like this |8:3|  when is supposed to be |8:30|, even if they resize the grid or window with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>scroll</kbd> it will appear bigger or smaller but like this |8:3|.

Code of grid.

```
tableToGrid('#grid_id',{
        multiselect: false,
        editurl: 'schedule_save.pl',
        shrinkToFit: true,
        ForceFit:false,
        width: 1270,
        hidegrid: false,
        rowNum: 100,
        autowidth:true,
        caption: totUsr + ' Registered Agents    -   Period $curr_period   -   Week $curr_week',
        colNames: ['Ref','ID', 'Full Name','Position','IN','OUT','B1','B2','LUNCH','IN','OUT','B1','B2','LUNCH','IN','OUT','B1','B2','LUNCH','IN','OUT','B1','B2','LUNCH','IN','OUT','B1','B2','LUNCH','IN','OUT','B1','B2','LUNCH','IN','OUT','B1','B2','LUNCH','Comment'],
        colModel: [
```